# Xamarin - DependencyService NULL

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, cross-platform

Caros, bom dia!

Comecei a ver um tutorial para desenvolver um app simples no Xamarin com o SQLite, mas eu estou com um problema, com um objeto que chama DependencyService,
le sempre vêm nulo, e eu não estou conseguindo achar a solução.

Segue abaixo o código fonte:

Classe de conexão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Interface IConfig:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu objeto config, está nulo, como ajusto isso? Cheguei a ler pra adicionar um atributo de [assembly: Depencendy(typeof(xxxxx))]. Eu não entendi sobre isso, não sei o que preciso passar no typeof, se passo minha classe atual, ou se passo a classe DependencyService.

Aguardo respostas.

Att.

Felipe Duarte

Comment: `[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ConfigDb))]` É uma anotação que deve constar na classe `(public class ConfigDb : IConfigDb)` específica para cada plataforma. Seu projeto é do tipo `xamarin forms`?

Answer (score 4):

Se você estiver utilizando Xamarin Forms, provavelmente você precisa implementar a interface IConfig em cada plataforma.
Por exemplo, no projeto MeuDb.Droid, adicione a seguinte classe:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ConfigDroid))]
namespace MeuDb.Droid
{
    public class ConfigDroid : IConfig
    {

        private string DiretorioSQLite
        {
            get
            {
                return Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            }
        }

        private ISQLitePlatform Plataforma
        {
            get
            {
                return new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Daí você precisa fazer a mesma implementação pras outras plataformas que estiver trabalhando, IOS ou Windows Phone.