# "You must call xamarin.forms.init() prior to using it" - Problema ao tentar acessar os dados do sqlite

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Olá,

Sou iniciante em programação mobile e estou empenhado em um projeto `PCL Xamarin` com `Xamarin.Forms`. A aplicação utiliza alarmes e para isso faço uso de injeção de dependência para acessar as classes nativas que cuidam das notificações. No `Android` utilizo a classe `AlarmManeger` que naturalmente tem os registros apagados quando o dispositivo é desligado. Para restaurar o alarmes eu criei uma classe no projeto `Android` que herda de `BroadcastReceiver` e dispara sob ação `ActionBootCompleted` e nela gostaria de acessar os dados do banco `SQLite` a partir do projeto `PCL`. Porém ao referenciar a conexão obtenho a seguinte exceção:

[image: Exception após a inicialização do dispositivo.]

Classe "BootReceiver" (projeto .Droid):

```
namespace NutriTime.Droid.Notification
{
  [BroadcastReceiver]
  [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted },
      Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault })]
  public class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
  {
      public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
      {           
          try
          {
              //A linha abaixo gera a Exception
              NutriTime.Data.RefeicaoRepository dados = new NutriTime.Data.RefeicaoRepository(NutriTime.App.DataBase); 

              //TODO:Manipulação dos dados

              Toast.MakeText(context, "Ok", ToastLength.Long).Show();
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              Toast.MakeText(context, e.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
          }
      }        
  }
}
```

Configuração do SQLite (projeto .Droid):

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(NutriTime.Droid.Data.SQLite_Android))]

namespace NutriTime.Droid.Data
{
  public class SQLite_Android : ISQLite
  {
     private string _diretorioDB;
     public string DiretorioDB
     {
         get
         {
             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_diretorioDB))
             {
                 _diretorioDB = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
             }
             return _diretorioDB;
         }
     }
     private SQLite.Net.Interop.ISQLitePlatform _plataforma;
     public ISQLitePlatform Plataforma
     {
        get
        {
            if (_plataforma == null)
            {
                _plataforma = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
            }
            return _plataforma;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Interface de abstração do SQLite (projeto Portable):

```
namespace NutriTime.Interfaces
{
  public interface ISQLite
  {
      string DiretorioDB { get; }
      ISQLitePlatform Plataforma { get; }
  }
}
```

Classe responsável pela criação do banco de dados (projeto Portable):

```
namespace NutriTime.Data
{
  public class DBConnection
  {
      private SQLiteConnection _con;
      public DBConnection()
      {
         var config = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>();
         _con = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(config.Plataforma, System.IO.Path.Combine(config.DiretorioDB, "nutritimedb.db3"));

         _con.CreateTable<PacienteModel>();
         _con.CreateTable<RefeicaoModel>();
         _con.CreateTable<AlimentoModel>();
         _con.CreateTable<ItemModel>();

       }
       public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
       {
          return _con;
       }
   }
}
```

**Qual a forma mais adequada para acessar os dados do SQLite dentro do projeto específico Android?**

Comment: O código mostrado não ajuda a identificar o problema, mostre o código de configuração do `SQLite` dentro da projeto `Android`. Para mais detalhes veja nessa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126353/xamarin-dependencyservice-null @dantas-j

Comment: @rubStackOverflow estás falando da implementação do SQLite no projeto android?

Comment: Exatamente @dantas-j

Comment: Coloque também o código onde está instanciando `SQLite_Android `. Quando está `debugando`onde exatamente o erro ocorre?

Comment: @rubStackOverflow o erro ocorre na classe BootReceiver que roda automaticamente quando o dispositivo inicializa. A linha do erro está indicada (linha 13).

Comment: Mais tarde vou comparar com meu código e tentar ajudar. @dantas-j

Comment: Esse código é executado quando o telefone é ligado correto? Executando um teste simples (sem precisar reiniciar) a conexão com o banco funciona? @dantas-j

Comment: @rubStackOverflow A conexão com o banco funciona perfeitamente nas classes de manipulação de dados (as Models) no projeto Portable. Na classe BootReceiver não sei rodar o código sem ter que reiniciar o dispositivo :/

Comment: Corrigindo: nas classes de manipulação de dados (as **ViewModels**)

Answer (score 1):

Depois de mais pesquisas percebi onde estava errando.

Na classe BootReceiver, onde têm-se

```
//A linha abaixo gera a Exception
          NutriTime.Data.RefeicaoRepository dados = new NutriTime.Data.RefeicaoRepository(NutriTime.App.DataBase);
```

Substitui por

```
            SQLite.Net.Interop.ISQLitePlatform plataforma = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
            string diretorioDB = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            using (SQLiteConnection _con = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(plataforma, System.IO.Path.Combine(diretorioDB, "nutritimedb.db3")))
            {
               //Manipulação de dados                      
            }
```

Basicamente, pelo o que entendi, eu estava tentando fazer acesso ao banco através das classes de acesso a dados presentes no projeto PCL (incluindo a classe App) que necessitam da inicialização do Xamarin.Forms.

Quem se sentir a vontade para explicar melhor ou complementar/corrigir minha resposta, sinta-se a vontade. Grato.

Aqui foi onde pude perceber meu erro: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715613/use-a-local-database-in-xamarin